# Will new install affect my boot?

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 20.04, mbr

I just started up a HP Pavilion x360 I haven't used for a couple of years. It runs Ubuntu from 2016 dual boot with Win10 and works fine. But I can not upgrade to 2018/20. Different errors. I wish to make a new install and keep the home partition. The 2020 Live USB works fine.

Current version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Intended install: ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64

What could happen during the install? Could the boot to Windows be affected? Should I prepare some recovery tools for MBR before I start? Isn't there a choice whether to rewrite MBR? etc etc

Please advice before I start if there could be any problems.

This is what boot looks like
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEBE1.jpg

Thank you

Comment: Yeas to all, and also backup all important files.

Comment: Thank you. So there will be no problems. I remember the UEFI gave problems at first install but hopefully not now, as I understand?

Comment: It looks like you want a list of all the things that can go wrong, which is a silly thing to ask, but the question makes no sense otherwise. Istallations can, and do go wrong, so make a backup, and have recovery media ready.

Comment: You haven't been specific as to releases; Ubuntu desktop systems (like Lubuntu you tagged) have a *year.month* format, which differ to the *snap* only releases intended for appliances/devices or cloud use that use *year* format (eg. Ubuntu Core 20).  Yes you can safely install one release over another without effect, but there are caveats for some I'd offer - but you've not provided any specifics as to release, or installer being used (multiple exist chosen by the ISO used to install)

Comment: I run 16.04 LTS dual boot with WIn 10. The 2020 I downloaded two days ago from the main site. I plan to first run the live USB and then click install. I believe my main question regards the boot. Will there be options regarding rewriting the MBR? And what boot recovery tool do you recommend. Maybe I should prepare a USB for that?

Comment: 2020?   There is no Ubuntu 2020; as releases are either *year.month* format, eg. 20.04 (2020-April release for server or desktop) or 20 (2020 release of a *specialized* server product intended for *headless* operation on devices/appliances or in the cloud).  No release is 2020 or 20.20 (no 20th month in a year)  You don't have a Ubuntu product, so check it's not a *forgery*   (Note: if it's 20.10 that release is EOL or *end-of-life*)

Comment: Sorry I didnt give the name properly: ubuntu-20.04.3-desktop-amd64

Comment: I believe the most important questions I have are 1. will there be options about rewriting MBR or similar and how should I choose   2. what boot recovery tool do you recommend, in case the boot fails (I remember UEFI gave problems on first install)

Comment: You should provide additional details & clarifications in main question and not provide details via comment. The ISO you mention in comments uses a `ubiquity` installer; but your tagged Lubuntu uses `calamares` so details contradict  (`calamares` doesn't give any choice as to MBR; but installation method detected is shown at the partitioning screen allowing you to know what type of install is being performed)

Comment: Thank you. Question edited. Sorry for misreading lubuntu for ubuntu. So please clarify, Will the ubiquity installer (I obviously have) give options (regarding boot) or problems with my UEFI dual boot and what boot recovery USB is recommended to prepare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Windows is installed in UEFI mode, boot and install Ubuntu the same way.  Windows 10 should already be in UEFI mode, unless it's a very old install upgraded from Windows 7 era or you deliberately chose MBR instead of GPT when installing Windows.

Make sure you have UEFI installation media. If you aren't sure how to do this, flash the ISO with balenaEtcher, since Etcher is very user-friendly and writes installation media that can be booted either UEFI or BIOS/compatibility.

You will need to consult with your motherboard's documentation if you have questions about how to boot in UEFI mode. This is dependent on what model motherboard you have and not related to Ubuntu itself.

UEFI is designed to handle multiple operating systems and the Ubuntu installer *should not* overwrite Windows' entries.  However, you should always keep sufficient backups of all important data, especially when manipulating partitions or installing operating systems. It kind of sounds like you are asking for assurance that nothing will go wrong and that is never the case: humans make mistakes all the time, hardware can fail at any time, and software does not always behave as expected, especially since everyone's combination of hardware and preexisting software is unique.  Back Up!

Comment: Thank you. The Win10 came with the computer. I know that all possibilities can not be covered, I just wanted to know if some obvious pitfalls could lie ahead. I will try the install later.  Thank you for your time. I will be back if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said in comments, it’s a bit of a broad question relating to what might happen.

My approach would be -

I don’t agree with the ‘so there will be no problems’ in your comment.

As soon as you are doing something as ‘invasive’ as installing a new release of your os over another in a dual boot system, almost anything bad could happen even though it will probably be fine. Assume there is a chance that any of these things happen (and more) -

- it’s all fine, new Ubuntu release works fine and you keep your old home folder
- installs fine but you have to manually copy your documents etc over
- failure to install the latest version of Ubuntu but the 16.04 release is damaged in the process
- after trying to install, you may find you can’t boot into windows
- small chance that nothing will boot up after your attempted upgrade, ie you have to start from scratch with installing both os’s.

Depending on your it skills, you may well be able to get back in even if windows disappears from the boot menu but you’ll need to know what you’re doing!

So the first thing to do is assume the worst and back up absolutely everything on both os’s and then try installing Ubuntu in the previous 16.04 partition. I’d also download and prepare the windows and Ubuntu installation media before starting so you can reinstall if it all goes wrong.

Lastly, assume this may well take time - ie to remedy any problems - so don’t start it in a short time window when you know you’ll need the computer soon after. Please excuse me if I’m stating things that are obvious to you.

I appreciate it’s not a complete answer to your question (hopefully others can answer the specifics), but please do work on the assumption it may not go smoothly!

Comment: Maybe I should have stated the question like "Are there any obvious pitfalls to prepare for?" I will try the installation later. thanks.

Comment: @cvr No problem with the question you asked from my perspective … good luck - let us know how you got on by posting a comment!